# Symfony 2 Form collection field no entity assignment

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following model:
One "Entry" has n "Tags"

I use a dynamic (javascript) form to edit the tags from my entry. I followed the [Symfony Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) to implement this.

But I have problems when I remove tags and add new ones at the same time. 
For example Tags get deleted which souldn't.

I know where the problem is originated:
Symfony assignes the submitted fields to the entities by their positions in the form. Since in the form every tag has only the field for its actual value (no id) there is no relation between the submittet fields and the entities.

So how can i deal with this? My first thougt would be to add a hidden field for every tag which contains the id of it. But is this the right way to do this in Symfony? And if yes, how can I implement this?

Comment: I had the same issue and the "best" solution i found (the simpliest actually) was to delete every relations each time the form was submitted and add the new ones (it's not a "good" solution but at least it works....). Not recommended if you've a lot of relations (like 30 tags for an entry...)

Comment: Yes that would be a soluton. But i think the problem wasn't one at all. I had an error in the javascript which sometimes causes the new field to have the same id as the previous one. I have to inspect this more close tomorrow but i think that was my problem.

Comment: when you say id you're talking about your entity id (sql) ? or css id?

Comment: Ok, id wasn't the right term. I meant field name.

Comment: ah okay, but it's normal because it's the same field that you duplicate in javascript. (Usually it's one field). Can you show us your entities (the entry and tags), you twig form and your php form?

Comment: Thats the mistake I made. You can't just duplicate the field. You have to change the name. You can use the prototype function which gives you a template for new entries: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an error in my javascript which sometimes caused new fields to get a duplicate name.